# org.w3c.dom.Document is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, domdocument

How should i fix this issue. I have been struggling with this for a day now and haven't made any progress. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

StackTrace: 
`12-Dec-2013 13:34:15.645 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mipStatus': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:369)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:537)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:332)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:478)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:690)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:540)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:252)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:454)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 35 more
    Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    org.w3c.dom.Document is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.w3c.dom.Document
        at private org.w3c.dom.Document com.abc.webservice.jaxws_asm.TakeXmlDoc.xmlDoc
        at com.abc.webservice.jaxws_asm.TakeXmlDoc
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:432)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:265)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:330)
    ... 46 more`

Code:

```
    package com.abc.webservice.impl;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import com.abc.model.Agent;
import com.abc.model.AuthHeader;
import com.abc.webservice.MipStatusWebService;
import com.abc.webservice.ProducerWebService;
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.abc.webservice.MipStatusWebService",
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org")
public class MipStatusWebServiceImpl implements MipStatusWebService {

  public static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MipStatusWebServiceImpl.class);

  public Document TakeXmlDoc(AuthHeader authHeader, Document xmlDoc) throws Exception {
    log.info("Inside TakeXmlDoc() with authHeader:-"+authHeader+" xmlDoc:-"+xmlDoc);
    return producerWebService.SyncScreeningStatus(Agent.MIP_NAME, xmlDoc);
  }

  private ProducerWebService producerWebService;
  public void setProducerWebService(ProducerWebService producerWebService){
    this.producerWebService = producerWebService;
  }  
}
```

springcontext file:

```
    <bean id="mipStatusWebService"
        class="com.abc.webservice.impl.MipStatusWebServiceImpl">
        <property name="producerWebService" ref="producerWebService" />
    </bean>
    <jaxws:endpoint id="mipStatus"
        implementorClass="com.abc.webservice.MipStatusWebService"
        implementor="#mipStatusWebService" address="/MipStatusService">
        <!--jaxws:serviceFactory>
            <ref bean="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory" />
        </jaxws:serviceFactory-->
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

That's what i have.
Trying to deploy it using tomcat but it is failing with the mentioned error.
NOTE: Updated content.

Comment: Explain in more detail what you're trying to do, show your code, copy and paste the exact error message including stack trace.

Comment: Existing code, error messages, efforts so far. We can't help you without these.

Comment: @Jesper added code and stackTrace.

Comment: @gyabraham added code and stackTrace.

Comment: Could you please post your com.sterling.ifn.webservice.jaxws_asm.TakeXmlDoc class code? I think you have a getter for xmlDoc returning a org.w3c.dom.Document interface, that's illegal for JAXB.

Comment: @vzamanillo i have updated description. yes, i have a method TakeXmlDoc which returns org.w3c.dom.Document.

Comment: Also, @vzamanillo could you please update your earlier post to com.abc.webservice.jaxws_asm.TakeXmlDoc?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hope this helps someone else.  I was getting this same error/exception.  My project was a simple Web Service using wsgen on an @WebService Java class.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

@WebService
public class WSControlPanel {

    /**
     * The ILogger variable
     */
    private Log                 log = LogFactory.getLog("org.adym.batch");
//
```

Turns out I had extra methods in my Web Service class called getLog() and setLog() that were returning and setting an apache log4j object.

```
public Log getLog() {
    return log;
}

public void setLog(Log log) {
    this.log = log;
}
```

Thus, when trying to instantiate the Web Service class, JAXB was trying to render operations for getLog() and setLog(), thus linking back to log4j...